# How can we getting elements index wise in LinkedList As it is said it stores Randomly

Tags: java, data-structures

It's said indexes in `LinkedList` Stored randomly but when i am trying the get the index in an "LinkedList" every time i am getting the same index. Then it's confusing how come it stores randomly  , here is below simple code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);
        
        System.out.println("Index At 2:::"+list.get(2));
        
        
        
        for (Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Integer integer = (Integer) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(integer);
            
        }
}
My output Every Time



Index At 2:::3
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it stores randomly"? A list has a fixed sequence of its elements, so the element at index position 2 is always the same.

Comment: Elements are stored consecutively in arrays whereas it is stored randomly in Linked lists. Ok what is the storage mechanism in LinkedList is it stores elements like index 1 , then 2 so on..?

Comment: @Henry then why they say accessing elements Linked list takes linear time, so it is quite a bit slower. As we can get the elements in a linkedList by index position?

Comment: Thanks clearing my doubt .. I think  many would have same doubt in LinkedList and Array i would like to give you some points for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory location of an element is not related to its logical position in the list. The list sequence is established by the links.

The index position refers to the position in the list, not the position in memory. To get to an element at a certain list index you must follow the links, that's why it is slower.